# typeinitializationexception was unhandled .The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I have created a Entity Framework DLL EMPDAL which points to Employees Table of Northwnd database. Below is the code for Entity framework

```
namespace EmpDAL{
public class EmplooyeeData
{
    public static List<Employee> GetEmployees( int EmployeeId)
    {
        using (DbEntities dbContext = new DbEntities())
        {
            return dbContext.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == EmployeeId).ToList();
        }
    }
    public static void SaveEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
        DbEntities dbContext = new DbEntities();
        dbContext.Employees.Add(emp);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}}
```

Below is the Appconfig file of EMPDAL

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EmployeeModel.csdl|res://*/EmployeeModel.ssdl|res://*/EmployeeModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=NorthWnd;user id=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Below is the code for the WCF service

```
namespace EmployeeService{

public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    public List<EmpDAL.Employee> GetEmployees(int Empid)
    {
        return EmpDAL.EmplooyeeData.GetEmployees(Empid);
    }

    public void SaveChanges(EmpDAL.Employee emp)
    {
        EmpDAL.EmplooyeeData.SaveEmployee(emp);
    }
}}
```

Below is the AppConfig for WCF EmployeeService

```
 <configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="EmployeeService.EmployeeService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EmployeeService.IEmployeeService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/EmployeeService/EmployeeService/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />  </configSections>  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DbEntities"connectionString="metadata=res://*/EmployeeModel.csdl|res://*/EmployeeModel.ssdl|res://*/EmployeeModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=NorthWnd;user id=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>  <entityFramework>   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,EntityFramework" /> </entityFramework></configuration>
```

When client uses the WCF service it and when it tries to execute "using (DbEntities dbContext = new DbEntities())" it goes to

```
 public partial class DbEntities : DbContext    {
    public DbEntities()
        : base("name=DbEntities")
```

and throws exception

```
typeinitializationexception was unhandled .The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.
```

Comment: show the config of the service ..

Comment: updated the question with AppConfig of Service

Comment: try to add DAL config to the service config, the service config might only need connection string element from the DAL

Comment: I tried that but did not work

Comment: could you also please check the inner exception.. there might be actual error message in there

Comment: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. only this exception it shows

Comment: You added `<connectionStrings><add name="DbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res....amework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>` under `Configuration` element on service config, right?

Comment: Thanks..yes I added the connection string in Appconfig or service. Also I have updated my post with Employee service Appconfig file.

Comment: I didn't aware you made a comment, I think the service assembly can't find the EF assembly, did you add reference to EF assembly on service project, if not, could you try add it?

Answer (score 0):

It is very generic exception so in your editor try reading the whole details of the exception and then resolve it.
For me, it was due to the entity framework version written in webconfig file and actual file included ,there was difference and also i had to remove providers tag in web config file of my project